# confused in simple probability: at least sum

Tags: probability

We are awarded multiple scores X[i] during a game we are playing. The scores awarded are given a probability P[i]. At the ith stage of the game, we either get the score X[i](with probability P[i]) or 0 (with probability (1-P[i])) and move on to the next stage. What is the probability that our total score in the end is at least S.
Say for instance we have scores

1000 2500 100 200 1800


0.5 0.2 1 0.2 0.2

And we are asked the probability that our score is at least 1800. Any idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to expand

$(.5+.5x^{1000})(.8+.2x^{2500})(x^{100})(.8+.2x^{200})(.8+.2x^{1800})$

and sum the coefficients of all the terms of the form $x^n$ with $n \ge 1800$.  It helps to have access to a computer algebra system if you do this.

Comment: is there an easier way

Comment: That's the easiest way I know.  There are other ways-- for example, you can write a computer program to solve the problem.